# How to restrict autofill for specific input tag?

Tags: html, autocomplete, attributes

I have an input tag which acts as a search box. But before that I have two input tags through which the credentials is given which gets saved in chrome browser. Now when the search box gets rendered it gets rendered with the autofill value of the username which was saved in the browser previously. My requirement is the **autofill** for the **search input** tag should not take place. I had used the following attributes for the search input tag but still it is not getting resolved.

`<input type="text" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" name="my_custom_name">`

Can anyone please provide me with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The latest way to do this is,Just simply use type `search`

```
<input type="search" />
```

Comment: I tried this, but still it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Then try this `<input name="q" type="search" autocomplete="off"/>`

Comment: I tried the above code snippet also but still I am not able to resolve the issue

Comment: Then try using this jQuery function
`$("input[type=text], input[type=number], input[type=email], input[type=password]").focus(function (e) {
    $(this).attr("autocomplete", "new-password");
})`

Comment: I tried using this still, it did not work for me. This issue occurs on key down action even though I did not trigger it. So on focus action the input text box is already filled with the autofill value. Can you please suggest me another solution?

Answer (score 0):

autocomplete="off" toggles the application auto complete. Chrome browser has "Auto-fill" feature, where users can enable/disable. Hope you are not talking about this.

[image]

Comment: No this is not what I am talking about. I need the autofill of the browser to be enabled and prevent the autofill action for one specific input tag alone.